# How can I remove a number of elements from a hash map?

Tags: rust

I need to keep a transposition table in a chess engine from growing infinitely, hence I made a small function to call between moves to clean things up a bit. The objective is to clean up only when necessary (more than 2.5 million entries) but then at least 100,000 so that the number of positions we're keeping track of is around 2,5 million all the time:

```
pub fn ttGarbageHash(&self, hash: &mut HashMap<Position, Transp>) {
    let size = hash.len();
    println!("# hash size is {}", size);
    if size <= 2_500_000 {
        println!("# no need for cleanup");
        return;
    }
    // clean at least 100,000
    let n = max(100_000, size - 2_500_000);
    let keys: Vec<_> = { hash.keys().take(n).collect() };
    for k in keys {
        hash.remove(k);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error on the `hash.remove(k)` line saying

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*hash` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/common.rs:442:13
    |
440 |         let keys: Vec<_> = { hash.keys().take(n).collect() };
    |                              ---- immutable borrow occurs here
441 |         for k in keys {
    |                  ---- immutable borrow later used here
442 |             hash.remove(k);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

After having tried numerous variations of the above like:

```
hash.keys().take(n).for_each(|k| hash.remove(k))
```

I'm kind of disheartened now and have no idea how to continue. Also, I simply do not understand why I cannot iterate over a hash and later remove something from it? How does it matter that I created a vector of keys and why do I need to borrow the hash at all? Is not the reference to the mutable hash that I have proof that no other reference may exist? Hence I should be able to read and write the hash as I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to why your code doesn't work, the answer is simple: `keys` returns an iterator over `&K`, not `K`. This means that your `keys` vec contains references to the keys inside the hashmap, not the keys themselves. Thus, you can't remove items from the hashmap, because the removals could cause the hashmap to shrink or for elements to be reordered, changing their locations in memory and invalidating the references.

The easiest workaround is to just clone the keys:

```rust
// notice the .cloned()
let keys: Vec<_> = { hash.keys().take(n).cloned().collect() };
for k in keys {
    hash.remove(&k);
}
```

Comment: Since cloning has a reputation of something that's best avoided in high-performance Rust code, it's worth pointing out that if the key type is non-allocating like a number or a tuple of numbers, "cloning" is as trivial as an assignment. And if your keys are `Copy`, you can use `.copied()` in preference to `.cloned()` to (statically) assert that the cloning is cheap.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation. I'm beginning to see the problem now. The keys can indeed be copied, it's just a 5-tuple of u64. I guess many newcomers have problems with the reference taking behind the scenes all over the place in rust, especially people like me who think in "values", not in "memory locations". But I see of course how it is important for performance, etc.

Comment: @Ingo It's a typical stumbling block for beginners. Later you learn to get used to it and avoid it by either copying when necessary or using `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` where possible (not in your case). See also my answer for avoiding allocation altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does a great job of explaining the issue. In addition to that explanation, note that you could also avoid allocation altogether:

```
// clean at least 100,000
for _ in 0..max(100_000, size - 2_500_000) {
    let key = *hash.keys().next().unwrap();  // unwrap: we've checked the size
    hash.remove(key);
}
```

Since `hash.keys().next().unwrap()` will evaluate to a reference to the key, the `*` in front of it copies it, avoiding the borrow checker issue from the question.

This approach avoids allocating a vector of hundreds of thousands 5-tuples of `u64` and is therefore more cache-friendly, so it has potential to be faster than the code from the question fixed to copy the keys. To be sure it's best to measure.

Comment: This is a nice idea. Not because the speed would matter too much in this case. It's a few 100 milliseconds, actually. But it's between moves, when it's the opponents turn. But you're right, the intermediate Vec is ugly. I'd most love something like `hash.keys().copied().for_each(...)`, but of course this doesn't work either. However, this was only the first, naive approach. Removing random positions is understandably not the thing we really want to do. It could be just the positions we need in the next move. So, there is enhancement and I'll happy to use the idioms I learn here.